# What is the function $[x-a]^+$ called?

Tags: functions

I'm searching for the "official" name of the function
$$
[x-a]^+=
\begin{cases}
0\quad &\text{if}\quad x\leq a,\\
x-a\quad &\text{if}\quad x>a.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts

Comment: The first case should be $x\le a$.

Comment: Well but, if $a<x≤0$, what will we do?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of [ramp functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function)? It's also common to call them "rectifier" in various fields.

Comment: @user3733558 ramp functions is the one I was searching for, thanks!